# Asp.net mvc3 UserControl Path error : Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls, path

I have a solution that contains 2 projects. In the first I realized the User Controls and I want to use them in the second project. I publish the first project in `DomaineName` and the second project in `DomaineName/Directory`

It's an ASP.net MVC3 solution, So I programmed a helper to add controls like this link http://malvinly.com/2011/02/28/using-web-forms-user-controls-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project/

```
 public static HtmlString RenderControl<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string path, Action<T> action) where T:UserControl
 {
        Page page= new Page();

        T control = (T)page.LoadControl(path);
        page.Controls.Add(control);

        if (action != null)
        { action(control); }

        using( StringWriter sw= new StringWriter())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page,sw,false);
            return new HtmlString(sw.ToString());
        }
}
```

In the master page of the second project I use the helper :

```
Html.RenderControl<BackOffice.Controls.widgetRecentComment>("../../Controls/widgetRecentComment.ascx")
```

But this error appears:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

And I can't use the `~` because my user controls are in `DomaineName` and not `DomaineName/Directory`

Can you help me please ??

Comment: Why not simply structure your project so you can use ~/controls it will make your life a lot easier and prevent trying to bypass a security function (parent paths)

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in IIS, where it doesn't let you access files outside the application root by using `..` in the file name.

If you have control over IIS on the server, you can change this setting, otherwise you simply can't use the controls from a different application.

Comment: I didn't know the stting to change in IIS. can you tel me how can I change it  please ? witch setting exactly ?

Comment: @soumayssa: I looked a bit, but I can't find it... A setting for ASP pages exist, and is called "Enable Parent Paths", but I haven't found a corresponding setting for ASP.NET. Ref: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/iis-aspnet.html